# Yii::Why the class value only change once？

Tags: php, yii

I use a ajaxlink on my view to add new row of my submitform. I need a index to indicate which row was created.so I use a class Variable to save the index。but I found the Variable only change once.

here is my code

```
public function actionNewrow()
{
    $this->i++;

    $form = new CActiveForm();
    $temp = new exportprice();

    array_push($this->exps, $temp);
    //echo count($this->exps);

    $i = count($this->exps)-1;

    $html = '<tr><td>'.
                $this->i.$form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname')
            .'</td>'.
            '<td>'.
                $form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend')
            .'</td>'.
            '<td>'.
                $form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin')
            .'</td></tr>';
    echo $html;
}

echo CHtml::ajaxLink("新增",
    Yii::app()->createUrl( 'InputReport/newrow' ),

    // ajax options
    array(
        'error' => 'function(data)   { alert("error!");  }',
        'success' => 'function(data) { $("#exptbl").append(data); }',
        'cache'=>false,
    ),

    // htmloptions
    array(
        'id' => 'handleClick',
    )
);
```

Comment: its better to use the variable `i` in clientside js and supply it as a parameter to ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are calling `actionNewrow` via AJAX to a pre-defined class varialbe `$i` which you inc each time? That would be why. PHP is not consistent to client side as such `$i` will always equal the previous value when used in this manner as such `++`ing it will merely make it inc once.

You will need some way on client side to send down the `$i` from dechipering it either:

- From the number of rows you have +1 (This is open to index duplications)
- Housing a $i var in JS and using that within a self defined function (probably outside of the `ajaxLink` builder) to propogate a new row using the `$i` var in JS as the class var.

A quick example for you:

```
var i = <?php echo $this->i // presuming i is a controller car you pass to the view ?>;

$('.add_new_row').on('click', function(){
    $.get('InputReport/newrow', {i:i}, function(data){
        //append your row now
        i++; // inc i here
    });
});
```

And then in your controller you would do something like:

```
public function actionNewrow($i = null)
{
    $i = $i===null ? $this->i++ : $i;

    $form = new CActiveForm();
    $temp = new exportprice();

    array_push($this->exps, $temp);
    //echo count($this->exps);

    $i = count($this->exps)-1;

    $html = '<tr><td>'.
                $this->i.$form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']productname')
            .'</td>'.
            '<td>'.
                $form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']trend')
            .'</td>'.
            '<td>'.
                $form->labelEx($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin').$form->textField($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin').$form->error($this->exps[0],'['.$i.']margin')
            .'</td></tr>';
    echo $html;
}
```

This should help you out a little hopefully,